# Substitute values in a cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array built like this for 64 rows:

`[1x8 double]    [1x8 double]    [-41.681792665672198]    [1.002916975562337e+03]    [1.002557764151239e+03] [    2.076740522329561]    [    6.976575556945958]`

Sometimes in the `[1x8 double]` cell I get a value I want to filter out. I use this filter:

```
           if RESULT{j,1}(1,n) > 1050
               RESULT{j,1}(1,n) = 'NaN'; 
           end
           if RESULT{j,1}(1,n) < 950
               RESULT{j,1}(1,n) = 'NaN';
           end
```

Unfortunately, MATLAB would give me this error:

`**Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts**`

It is strange enough, that the program wouldn't give me this error thorough the processing, but after I explecically called for that function in the command window.

I want to use this substitution to then calculate mean and standard deviation without those odd values:

```
if RESULT{j,1} ~=0
RESULT{j,4} = nanmean(RESULT{j,1});
RESULT{j,5} = nanmean(RESULT{j,2});
RESULT{j,6} = nanstd(RESULT{j,1});
RESULT{j,7} = nanstd(RESULT{j,2});
end
```

So if you might have anouther solution for that, I'm all yours :)

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce exactly the same error you have, but i think the problem lies in how you assign the NaN values, you should not assign it as a string, but call the NaN function instead:
i.e. NaN instead of 'NaN'
In your code:

```
if RESULT{j,1}(1,n) > 1050
   RESULT{j,1}(1,n) = NaN; 
end
if RESULT{j,1}(1,n) < 950
   RESULT{j,1}(1,n) = NaN;
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Doesn't help though, I think it's a bit more complex - it involves going from function to function and I'm not sure I understand this one properly.

Comment: you should try to break it down to a minimal example and work your way from there to see where the problem is